# How can all options from a drop-down list (select) box be tested in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can we select all `options` from a normal drop-down list box and verify them using Cypress?

```html
<select id="cars_list">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

```js
//The below test can check only for one option, how can we verify the rest? 

describe("Select all values from drop down list", function() {
  it("Cypress test and verify all options", function() {
  cy.visit("Https://sometestingsite.com")  
  cy.get('#cars_list').then(function($select){
   $select.val('volvo')
   })
   cy.get('select').should('have.value', 'volvo')
   });
});
```

Comment: Have you considered some kind of a loop? But is it really valuable to test that if you select a value that value is selected?

Comment: Perhaps the bad code obscures the question - I think the test is to confirm the option list has expected values - can you confirm @soccerway?

Comment: Yes I would like to confirm the `option list` has expected values. Some one down voted though, don't know why ?

Comment: Sorry for harsh comment about your code. Could you please show the DOM on the select element? I think you might use something like `cy.get('#cars_list').its('options').then(options => ...)`.

Comment: Ok, DOM is exactly as you already show. Maybe `cy.get('#cars_list option').then(options => ...)` suits?

Comment: I have added the DOM image

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest the test might look like this

```js
cy.get('#cars_list option').then(options => {
  const actual = [...options].map(o => o.value)
  expect(actual).to.deep.eq(['volvo', 'saab', 'mercedes', 'audi'])
})
```

OR

```js
cy.get('#cars_list').children('option').then(options => {
  const actual = [...options].map(o => o.value)
  expect(actual).to.deep.eq(['volvo', 'saab', 'mercedes', 'audi'])
})
```

OR

```js
cy.get('#cars_list').find('option').then(options => {
  const actual = [...options].map(o => o.value)
  expect(actual).to.deep.eq(['volvo', 'saab', 'mercedes', 'audi'])
})
```

Selecting multiple child elements with `cy.get()`, then unwrapping them with `[...options]`, mapping to their value with `.map(o => o.value)` and using a deep equal to compare arrays.

I have not tested this, so the code may need some tweaking.

Comment: I am getting an error like `cypress_runner.js:161489 TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`

Comment: Maybe console.log the options. We are expecting Cypress to select multiple elements, so it should be iterable.

Comment: I just noticed you asked about the downvote. Was not me, I upvoted. Probably just some troll passing through.

Comment: No problem Hiram, this work with the above code HTML DOM. But can I ask one last thing, if `select` tag has got `<option selected="selected" disabled="true">--Please Select --</option>` in the html DOM, while running the its counting array 5, as AssertionError: expected [ Array(5) ] to deeply equal [ Array(4) ]

Comment: Seems like you need to take a look at javascript array documentation? Would help in constructing your tests. The `slice()` function can be used to take a subset of an array.

Comment: Thanks, I use shift() to remove the first value, all good now

Comment: That is one I didn't know, seems a better choice than `slice()`